# Where are downloaded .apk files of applications stored in BlueStacks?

Tags: windows, bluestacks

I have downloaded and installed a heavy file lately on BlueStacks. Now I want to uninstall bluestacks but don't want to have to download the same software all over again.

If I could locate where the downloaded apk has been kept (I downloaded the file through playstore in BlueStacks), I could copy it and keep a backup on my windows so that I can copy it over to any other android emulator.

Any help on that?

Comment: I think the trick mentioned [here](http://apkreview4u.blogspot.in/2013/04/how-to-get-apk-file-from-bluestacks-app.html) should work. It expects you to download a backup app from Play Store and use it to make backup of an app's APK into sdcard.

Comment: I tried. It says the software (Carnivores: Dinosaur Hunter HD) is "protected" and cannot be backed up. Anyhow, thanks for the effort sir.